# ChainLink VRF requestRandomnes() failing

Tags: chainlink, chainlink-vrf

Here is the txn on sepolia: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xb530e49bb505fad002923e957d784a4fa18084b65d79eabd4fc29b326a7e797e

Given below is the Factory contract that deploys a Raffle contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
import "./Raffle.sol";
contract RaffleFactory{
address immutable owner;
    constructor()    {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    Raffle[] public lotteries;
    // event ContractCreated(uint256 index);
    function NewRaffle(address vrfCoordinatorV2,
    address linktoken,
        uint256 interval,
        uint256 entranceFee,
        uint32 callbackGasLimit)public returns(Raffle){
        address deployer = msg.sender;
        Raffle newRaffle = new Raffle(vrfCoordinatorV2, link, interval, entranceFee, callbackGasLimit, owner,deployer);
        lotteries.push(newRaffle);
        
        // emit ContractCreated(index);
        return newRaffle;
    }
    function getRaffle(uint256 _index) public view returns(address){
        return(address(lotteries[_index]));
    }
    function getRafflelatest() public view returns(address){
        return(address(lotteries[lotteries.length -1]));
    }

}
```

The Raffle Contract is given as:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFV2WrapperConsumerBase.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/LinkTokenInterface.sol";

import "hardhat/console.sol";

error Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(uint256 currentBalance, uint256 numPlayers, uint256 raffleState);
error Raffle__TransferFailed();
error Raffle__SendMoreToEnterRaffle();
error Raffle__RaffleNotOpen();

contract Raffle is ConfirmedOwner,VRFV2WrapperConsumerBase {
    /* Type declarations */
    enum RaffleState {
        OPEN,
        CALCULATING
    }
    /* State variables */
    // Chainlink VRF Variables
    // VRFV2WrapperInterface private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
    // LinkTokenInterface private  immutable i_link;
    // uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionId;
    // bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
    uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;

    // Lottery Variables
    uint256 private immutable i_interval;
    uint256 private s_lastTimeStamp;
    address private s_recentWinner;
    address public i_owner;
    address private immutable deployer;
    // modifier onlyOwner override  {
    //     require(msg.sender == owner);
    //     _;
    // }
    
    uint256 private immutable i_entranceFee;
    address payable[] private s_players;
    RaffleState private s_raffleState;

    /* Events */
    event RequestedRaffleWinner(uint256 indexed requestId);
    event RaffleEnter(address indexed player);
    event WinnerPicked(address indexed player);

    /* Functions */
    constructor(
        address vrfCoordinatorV2,
        address linkAddress,
        // uint64 subscriptionId,
        // bytes32 gasLane, // keyHash
        uint256 interval,
        uint256 entranceFee,
        uint32 callbackGasLimit,
        address _owner,
        address _deployer
    ) VRFV2WrapperConsumerBase(linkAddress,vrfCoordinatorV2) ConfirmedOwner(_deployer) {
        // i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        // i_vrfCoordinator = VRFV2WrapperInterface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        // i_link = LinkTokenInterface(linkAddress);
        // i_gasLane = gasLane;
        i_interval = interval;
        // i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        i_entranceFee = entranceFee;
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
        i_owner = _owner;
        deployer = _deployer;
    }

    function enterRaffle() public payable {
        // require(msg.value >= i_entranceFee, "Not enough value sent");
        // // require(s_raffleState == RaffleState.OPEN, "Raffle is not open");
        if (msg.value < i_entranceFee) {
            revert Raffle__SendMoreToEnterRaffle();
        }
        if (s_raffleState != RaffleState.OPEN) {
            revert Raffle__RaffleNotOpen();
        }
        s_players.push(payable(msg.sender));
        // Emit an event when we update a dynamic array or mapping
        // Named events with the function name reversed
        emit RaffleEnter(msg.sender);
    }

    /**
     * @dev This is the function that the Chainlink Keeper nodes call
     * they look for `upkeepNeeded` to return True.
     * the following should be true for this to return true:
     * 1. The time interval has passed between raffle runs.
     * 2. The lottery is open.
     * 3. The contract has ETH.
     * 4. Implicity, your subscription is funded with LINK.
     */
    function checkUpkeep(
        bytes memory /* checkData */
    )
        public
        view
        returns (
            bool upkeepNeeded,
            bytes memory /* performData */
        )
    {
        bool isOpen = RaffleState.OPEN == s_raffleState;
        bool timePassed = ((block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval);
        bool hasPlayers = s_players.length > 0;
        bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;
        upkeepNeeded = (timePassed && isOpen && hasBalance && hasPlayers);
        return (upkeepNeeded, "0x0"); // can we comment this out?
    }

    /**
     * @dev Once `checkUpkeep` is returning `true`, this function is calledun
     * and it kicks off a Chainlink VRF call to get a random winner.
     */
    function performUpkeep(
        // bytes calldata /* performData */
    ) external onlyOwner {
        // (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
        // require(upkeepNeeded, "Upkeep not needed");
        // if (!upkeepNeeded) {
        //     revert Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(
        //         address(this).balance,
        //         s_players.length,
        //         uint256(s_raffleState)
        //     );
        // }
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.CALCULATING;
        // uint256 linkAmount = 0.25*(10**18);
        // LINK.approve(msg.sender, linkAmount);
        // LINK.transferFrom(msg.sender,address(this), linkAmount);
        // require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this))>linkAmount);
        uint256 requestId = requestRandomness(i_callbackGasLimit,REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,NUM_WORDS);

        emit RequestedRaffleWinner(requestId);
    }

    /**
     * @dev This is the function that Chainlink VRF node
     * calls to send the money to the random winner.
     */
    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256, /* requestId */
        uint256[] memory randomWords
    ) internal override {
        // s_players size 10
        // randomNumber 202
        // 202 % 10 ? what's doesn't divide evenly into 202?
        // 20 * 10 = 200
        // 2
        // 202 % 10 = 2
        uint256 indexOfWinner = randomWords[0] % s_players.length;
        address payable recentWinner = s_players[indexOfWinner];
        address payable m_owner = payable(i_owner);
        address payable i_deployer = payable(deployer);
        s_recentWinner = recentWinner;
        s_players = new address payable[](0);
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        uint256 commision = (address(this).balance)/20;
        // m_owner.transfer(commision);
        // bool success1 = m_owner.send(commision);
        // i_deployer.send(commision);
        (bool comm1, ) = m_owner.call{value: commision}("");
        (bool comm2, ) = i_deployer.call{value: commision}("");
        (bool success, ) = recentWinner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        // require(success, "Transfer failed");
        if (!success) {
            revert Raffle__TransferFailed();
        }
        emit WinnerPicked(recentWinner);
    }

    /** Getter Functions */

    function getRaffleState() public view returns (RaffleState) {
        return s_raffleState;
    }

    function getNumWords() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return NUM_WORDS;
    }

    function getRequestConfirmations() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS;
    }

    function getRecentWinner() public view returns (address) {
        return s_recentWinner;
    }

    function getPlayer(uint256 index) public view returns (address) {
        return s_players[index];
    }

    function getLastTimeStamp() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_lastTimeStamp;
    }

    function getInterval() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_interval;
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_entranceFee;
    }

    function getNumberOfPlayers() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_players.length;
    }
    function withdrawLink() public onlyOwner {
        require(
            LINK.transfer(msg.sender, LINK.balanceOf(address(this))),
            "Unable to transfer"
        );
    }
}
```

The original code was based on the subscription model of chailink vrf
.I have modified it to be a direct funding vrf.

I need to pick the Raffle winner by calling the performUpkeep() which calls the requestRandomness in the VRFV2Wrapper and then eventually calling fulfillRandomWords and emiting the winner

I get the error Fail with error 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance' Eventhough the smart contract have enough LINK to pay the VRF function
The errorcode is :

```
 code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
 transactionHash: '0xb530e49bb505fad002923e957d784a4fa18084b65d79eabd4fc29b326a7e797e'
```

Here is the code I use to call the performUpkeep()

```
const grouplottery1 = new ethers.Contract(groupexist1[0].address, contract.abi, wallet)
                    const vrfwraper = new ethers.Contract("0xab18414CD93297B0d12ac29E63Ca20f515b3DB46",vrfabi,wallet);
                    const amnt = await vrfwraper.calculateRequestPrice("5000000")
                    console.log(wallet.address)
                    const linktoken = new ethers.Contract("0x779877A7B0D9E8603169DdbD7836e478b4624789",linkabi,wallet)
                    // const linkfee = parseEther("0.5")
                    // const trnsfr = await linktoken.transferFrom(wallet.address,(groupexist1[0].address),amnt,{gasLimit: 5000000})
                    // const tx1 = trnsfr.wait()
                    const checkData = ethers.utils.keccak256(ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes(""))
                   
                    const { upkeepNeeded } = await grouplottery1.callStatic.checkUpkeep(checkData)
                    if (upkeepNeeded) {
                      
                        const tx = await grouplottery1.performUpkeep({gasLimit: 5000000})
                       
                        const txReceipt = await tx.wait(1)
                       
                        // const requestId = txReceipt.events![1].args!.requestId
                        // console.log(`Performed upkeep with RequestId: ${requestId}`)

                        await grouplottery1.on('RequestedRaffleWinner',async (msg)=>{
.....
                            });
```

Comment: Can you make sure that you are using Wrapper address instead of Coordinator address in Raffle's constructor? If you want to use direct funding for VRF, you should use wrapper address but it looks that you input coordinator in raffle's constructor. You can find the wrapper address on sepolia [here](https://docs.chain.link/vrf/v2/direct-funding/supported-networks#sepolia-testnet)

Comment: Yes the variable name is vrfcoordinator but I input the wrapper address , I didn't change the variable when changing to direct funding

Comment: I tried your `Raffle` in remix and the request can be sent successfully.

Comment: @FrankKong Can you try deploying Raffle with Raffle Factory and then sending the request if you don`t mind

Comment: ```
const newlottery = await Factory.NewRaffle("0xab18414CD93297B0d12ac29E63Ca20f515b3DB46","0x779877A7B0D9E8603169DdbD7836e478b4624789","30", raffleEntranceFee, "5000000")
````
These are the input params I used 
1. wraper adress, 2.link address, 3. interval of 30s, 4. an entry fee of 0.01eth,5. calllback gaslimit

Comment: If you directly deploy `raffle` without factory, can you successfully send the VRF request?

Comment: Once it was successful but later it didn't work for me